# jQuery version conflict - load two versions same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-1.9, jquery-1.6

In my regular project setup we are using jQuery v1.6.2, but recently we have started to use Kendo UI plugin for charts; this plugin won't support the jQuery version v1.6.2, it works only with v1.7 or higher, so we are forced to load v1.7 also using `noConflict`.

Are there any side effects to my existing old code? Can we load and use two versions of jQuery at the same time?

Comment: why cant you just use latest jquery 1.11.x version ?

Comment: Does your existing code break going from 1.6.2 to 1.7? If not, just drop 1.6.2 and only use 1.7.

Comment: I would try using RequireJS. You probably can't use both versions in the same block of code, but it should allow you to load and contain both versions in separate files.

Comment: highly unlikely that you can't just upgrade 1.6. Loading 2 versions is rarely necessary and is extra page overhead

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it. Using `jQuery.noConflict()` you can make multiple versions of jQuery coexist on the same page:

```
<script src='jquery-1.3.2.js'></script>
<script>
    var jQ132 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src='jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>
<script>
    var jQ142 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

*extracted from [jQuery forums](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)*

Later, you just use `jQ16` instead of `$`, e.g.:

```
<script>
    jQ16.ready(function($) {
        // inside here, $ refers to jQ16
        $('#something').val(); // ...
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In this special case I would say use `var jQ17 = jQuery.noConflict()` for v.1.7.0+ and leave the other one as is, so that the existing code wont break - for the kendo stuff the jQ17 can be used

Comment: Thank you so much  kmsdev, charlietfl. got the clear idea about it.

Comment: the other answers in stackoverflow was too old. i'm happy to see the updated answer in 2015. and lucky nobody voted you down.